# x' = M x: Help me find a different eigenhammer.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve "simple" and sparse linear ODEs in matrix form of the type $\dot{\vec{x}} = M \vec{x}$ for initial value problems with a given $\vec{x}(t=0) \equiv \vec{x}_0$ and a time-independent $n\times n$ matrix $M$. Sometimes $M$ is hermitian and most often it is real but not symmetric (e.g. rate equations). Now I know that the solution is $\vec{x}(t) = e^{M t} \vec{x}_0$.

My problem is of the "everything looks like a nail" type: I would usually solve this by doing an eigenvalue decomposition $M = P D P^{-1}$ and calculate $\vec{x}(t) = P e^{D t} P^{-1} \vec{x}_0$, which I can do reasonably well even in matlab or numpy as long as I have enough memory to vectorize over all times of interest.

However, I find myself having to calculate all eigenvalues of a largish (let's say $n = 1000$ or more) matrix $M$ and it seems that this becomes inefficient, especially when considering the case of sparse $M$.

How would you solve this more efficiently? I would like to be able to calculate time dependent solutions for many different $M$ in a reasonable time (reasonable of course with respect to a typical laptop and typical attention spans).

Thanks for your input,

Sebastian

Comment: Maybe you could try using a method for numerically solving ODEs like a Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you just truncated the Taylor series for $e^{Mt}$, keeping only the first five terms or something.  $M^5 x_0$ could be computed by repeatedly applying $M$ to $x_0$, which is efficient due to the sparsity of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! Both of the comments actually amount to the same thing since RK4 turns into the 4th order Taylor expansion of $e^{Mt}$ when plugging the ODE into the Runge-Kutta formulas. The only problem now is that you need to decide on a time step for applying either RK4 or the 4th order Taylor expansion. My go-to heuristic for these decisions is to calculate the largest eigenvalue of $M$ (corresponding to the fastest time scale in the problem) and take (say) 10% of this rate as the minimal time step. What is your take on that?

Comment: Hammer/Nail, by the way. I assume there is a clever way (Lanczos) to get only the largest eigenvalue. On the other hand, is there really no better way to solve a linear ODE than solving an eigenvalue problem?

Comment: hmm, what are the standard step size heuristics that people use with Runge-Kutte methods? For example, what does the Matlab function ode45 use? (And does ode45 work well on this problem?) Perhaps a simpler step size strategy would work well.

Comment: All good ODE solvers use adaptive step-size control (dynamic feedback on the step size) instead of my overly cautious brute-force heuristic that works also for stiff systems. Doing this amounts to more right-hand-side evaluations of the ODE. My main beef with the whole approach was that it does not scale well with higher number of time steps and you gain only as long as the computational effort due to the number of steps ($\propto$ number of matrix multiplications) is smaller than the effort spent otherwise up front on diagonalization. But:

Comment: I guess it pays to read the documentation, thanks! The matlab solvers can also take into account that my Jacobian ($=M$) is constant and sparse to speed things up and I can define time points of interest between which it does whatever step size is necessary. I guess there is no free lunch after all, but if I use a clever algorithm it should work as fast as possible.